# Set a non-standard validation error message in Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, validation, error-handling

I am working on a basic **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8.

The application has a registration form. You have to accept the *Terms and Conditions* to register.

I have this valdation rule:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('terms', 'Terms and Conditions', 'required');
```

The problem with the above line is that it outputs the standard error message "The Terms and Conditions field is required", while i want "You have to accept out Terms and Conditions".

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer in the documentation:

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('field_name', 'Field Label', 'rule1|rule2|rule3',
        array('rule2' => 'Error Message on rule2 for this field_name')
);
```

Then on your code you should have something like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('terms', 'Terms and Conditions', 'required', array ('required' => 'You must accept the Terms and Conditions'));
```